# How to Count Non Blank Cells which Depends on another criterion/column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that will count all non blank cells within a range if there is a specific value for another column.

```
Column A  Column B   Column C
Anne       Jan 16       AO
Tina       Aug 12       VO
Perry      Mar 31       AO
Gab                     AO
Mallows                 VO
```

With this, i need to **count ALL NON-BLANK cells** if:
`Column C = "AO"`
`Column C = "VO"`

I tried this formula but seems to count all including blank cells.

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C, "AO", B:B, "<>COUNTBLANK(B2:B5)")
=COUNTIFS(C:C, "VO", B:B, "<>COUNTBLANK(B2:B5)")
```

The result should be

```
If Column C is AO, the result is **2**.
If Column C is VO, the result is **1**.
```

Can you help me with this? Your prompt response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C, "AO",B:B, "<>")
=COUNTIFS(C:C, "VO",B:B, "<>")
```

Answer (score 1):

to get 3 in a single shot

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C1:C5="AO")+(C1:C5="VO"),--(B1:B5<>""))
```